# flutter - how to set error style of TextFormField?

Tags: flutter

I want to change the style of the error that appear automatic after validate field. Can I do it? there is no field of error design in TextFormField API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this:

```dart
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(errorStyle: TextStyle(...)), //your desired style here
),
```